# Почему не работает флекс-бокс в блоке?

Tags: flexbox

Хочу выравнять стрелки перелистывания слайдов в Vue Carousel 3D посередине, но не могу понять почему не получается. Сами стрелки находятся в блоке .carousel-3d-controls и этому блоку я задал

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

но в итоге ничего не получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь код jsfiddle.net/jbtLyrfk/
сам сайт tempesho.beget.tech

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),        [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

У ваших стрелок задан position: absolute. Поэтому flex в родительском блоке игнорируется.
Чтобы выравнять по центру можно добавить:

```
.next, .prev {
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```